# css table select cells on long diagonal

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using CSS, I want to format a table like this:

[image: Screenshot from LibreOffice showing the desired table format]

The most difficult part is to have a black background for all the cells over a long diagonal: the cells where `<row nr> = <column nr> + 1` excluding the first row. I want to use the same CSS for different tables which are similar but with a different number of rows and columns.

Can this be done using CSS only? How?

---

fwiw, the table's HTML code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td> <td>name</td>
    <td>1</td> <td>2</td> <td>3</td> <td>4</td> <td>5</td>
    <td>total</td> <td>//</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td> <td>abc</td>
    <td>X</td> <td>9</td> <td>11</td> <td>8</td> <td>10</td>
    <td>38</td> <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td> <td>defgh</td>
    <td>7</td> <td>X</td> <td>8</td> <td>10</td> <td>10</td>
    <td>35</td> <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td> <td>ijk lmn</td>
    <td>5</td> <td>8</td> <td>X</td> <td>9</td> <td>11</td>
    <td>33</td> <td>9</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td> <td>op qr st uv</td>
    <td>8</td> <td>6</td> <td>7</td> <td>X</td> <td>12</td>
    <td>33</td> <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td> <td>wxyz</td>
    <td>6</td> <td>6</td> <td>5</td> <td>4</td> <td>X</td>
    <td>21</td> <td>5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Not very "dynamic", but... http://jsfiddle.net/9shebq2h/ (And [this modification](http://jsfiddle.net/9shebq2h/2/) is perhaps safer.)

Comment: If you couple that with something like SCSS, it could become more dynamic

Comment: @JaredFarrish Yes, using <thead> is better, thanks. And the css is remarkably simple, I just couldn't wrap my head around it myself, though. Great! Are their any hidden ill effects to be feared it the css is expanded to http://jsfiddle.net/0gh4tLnh/ even for those tables where there aren't that many rows and columns? If not, I can live with that not very "dynamic" but straightforward approach...

Comment: @beautifulcoder I never even heard of SCSS, and a quick read of the wiki page confuses me: is this something eventually browsers should support, or is it some intermediate code that should be parsed/compiled into css?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. I'd preface it with a class so it's not done on all tables, but that looks fine to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explicit way would be:

```
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3), 
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4), 
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(5), 
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(4) td:nth-child(6), 
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(5) td:nth-child(7), 
.diagonal tbody tr:nth-child(6) td:nth-child(8) {
    background-color: black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9shebq2h/3/

And that can be extended to include the greatest width needed for your table with additional selectors (as the OP has already pointed out in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you go with SCSS, you can just do:

```
@for $i from 2 through 7 {
    tr:nth-child($i) td:nth-child($i + 1) {
        background-color: black;
    }
}
```

SCSS works like a programming language. It saves you from writing copious amount of repetitive CSS. It needs a preprocessor, so you just need to find what fits within your tool chain.